# Reduce Spacing in ScientificForm

Tags: output-formatting

I am using ScientificForm to display my numbers. For example:

```
Style[ScientificForm[500000., NumberPoint -> Automatic], Black, 
 FontSize -> 50, FontFamily -> "Arial"]
```

gives the following result:

[image]

How do I reduce the spacing between the x and the two numbers?

Answer (score 3):

You could add an AdjustmentBox

```
Manipulate[
  Style[ScientificForm[500000., NumberPoint -> Automatic], Black, FontSize -> 50, FontFamily -> "Arial"] //
    ToBoxes //
    ReplaceAll[s : SuperscriptBox[__] :> AdjustmentBox[s, BoxMargins -> {{-shift, 0}, {0, 0}}]] //
    DisplayForm, 
  {shift, 0, .5}
]
```

[image: manipulate]

Answer (score 3):

Try the NumberFormat option:

```
NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "\[Times]", Superscript[#2, #3]}] &)
```

So, the full expression:

```
Style[
  ScientificForm[500000., 
    NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "\[Times]", Superscript[#2, #3]}] &), 
    NumberPoint -> Automatic], 
  Black, FontSize -> 50, FontFamily -> "Arial"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

x = 500000.;

{man, exp} = {10*#[[1]], #[[2]] - 1} &@MantissaExponent[x]

(* {5., 5} *)
```

Using no space

```
Style[Row[{Round@man, "\[Times]", Superscript[10, exp]}], Black, 
 FontSize -> 50, FontFamily -> "Arial"]
```

[image]